# add the newest added item to the lisbtox

Tags: c#

while working on an project i just can't seem to figure out how to add the newest added item to the lisbtox.

this is the code for adding a new article in the form (what i want to show in the list box after it is made):

```
 if (rbNormal.Checked)
 {
     articleManager.AddArticle(new NewsArticle(Convert.ToInt32(txtNewsNumber.Text), txtNewsTitle.Text, txtNewsText.Text, false));
     lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Clear();
 }
```

the code in articleManager:

```
 //Add article
 public void AddArticle(Article article)
 {
     items.Add(article);
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Be specific.

Comment: whenever a new article is made, i want to show it in the listbox. I can't figure out how to do it. I know that i need lbSeeNewsItems.Add() but i have no idea what to put inside of the ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lbSeeNewsItem is your listbox, then you are just clearing it:

```
lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Clear();
```

If it's done on purpose, then just add your article like:

```
lbSeeNewsItem.Items.Add(article);
```

where `article` is the one NewsArticle just created.
Important thing is that you have to override ToString() method in Article or NewsArticle to return the string that should be visible in ListBox. As ListBox reads its content from ToString() method. So for example:

```
class Article
{
   public string Title {get; set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
        return Title;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to identify the last added article.  As you control adding article via your `ArticleManager`, then you can do this here.

Add the following new property to `ArticleManager` class

```
public Article LastAddedArticle { get; private set; } = null;
```

Then change the adding method

```
public void AddArticle(Article article)
{
    LastAddedArticle = article;
    items.Add(article);
}
```

Then you just look in `articleManager.LastAddedArticle` to get the last one added.  Bear in mind that this can be null, so you may need to check!